# How to optimize for loop

Tags: database, oracle, for-loop, optimization, plsql

I need to optimize the for loop used in the PLSQL function. That function is used for making the report, but it takes too long (about 1 hour). Here is the code:

```
select c.id id_constr, s.id id_side, 
       coalesce(datumz, tz_date(2099, 12).datum) datum_z
  BULK COLLECT INTO arr_idConstruction, arr_idSide, arr_datumZ  
  from sp_constructions c, sp_constr_sides s
 where c.id = s.id_construction
 order by c.nummer, s.id;

for n_month in 1..12 loop

    nArbeit := 0;
    nTRS    := 0;
    nTSJ    := 0;
    nLight  := 0;
    dDate  := tz_date(pnYear, n_month).datum;

    FOR idx IN 1 .. arr_idConstruction.COUNT LOOP

      select coalesce(sum(kost_beim_bit), 0)
        into nArbeit_
        from table(dd_side_arbeit.f(arr_idSide(idx))) a
       where a.aktiv = 1
         and a.datum between tz_date(pnYear, n_month).d01 and last_day(tz_date(pnYear, n_month).d01);

      nArbeit := nArbeit + nArbeit_;

      nTRS := nTRS + dd_bewerbung.f_trs_anrechnen(
                                                 arr_idSide(idx),
                                                 dDate,
                                                 add_months(dDate, 1)-1
                                                 );

      if ( dDate <= arr_datumZ(idx) ) then

          begin

            select tsj, light
              into nTSJ_, nLight_
              from (select tsj, light
                      from t_constr_side_expenses s
                     where dDate >= s.datum
                       and s.id_side = arr_idSide(idx)
                     order by datum desc)
             where rownum = 1;

            nTSJ   := nTSJ   + nvl(nTSJ_,   0);
            nLight := nLight + nvl(nLight_, 0);

          exception
            when others then null;
          end;

      end if;

    end loop;

    select sum(b.betrag)
      into nBez
      from t_vertrag_bezahlung b
     where b.datum between dDate and
           add_months(dDate, 1) - 1;

    ttnArbeit.extend; ttnArbeit(ttnArbeit.count) := nArbeit;
    ttnTRS.extend;    ttnTRS(ttnTRS.count)       := nTRS;
    ttnTSJ.extend;    ttnTSJ(ttnTSJ.count)       := nTSJ;
    ttnLight.extend;  ttnLight(ttnLight.count)   := nLight;
    ttnENP.extend;    ttnENP(ttnENP.count)       := round(nArbeit*nENP_prz);
    ttnBez.extend;    ttnBez(ttnBez.count)       := nBez;

    tpMX.extend;
    tpMX( tpMX.count ) := tt_varchar2(  d2c( dDate ),
                                        nArbeit,
                                        nTRS,
                                        nTSJ,
                                        nLight,
                                        round(nArbeit*nENP_prz),
                                        nBez
                                      );

  end loop;
```

The collection **arr_idConstruction** has about 1000 records and  there are some calculations that need to be performed for each month of the year. So, this code is executed approximately 12000 times (12 months x 1000 recods). 
Is there any way to optimize this code?

Comment: You should rewrite it using set-based logic.

Comment: I see only loops in your code, so, no "optimizing"  them anyway. Simply get rid of them and restructure the code to perform plain SQLs.

Comment: @KaushikNayak the functions used inside loops make a lot of processing and the logic is quite complicated, so I can't just substitute the function call with a plain SQL query. Therefore, I'm so confused and I don't understand how to speed up this code. Before there were cursors used and I rewrote it using bulk collect and removed as much code as I could outside the loop. But the performance didn't seem to change.

Comment: I don't think the loop is the problem. It's hard to help if we don't see every part of the code. Try to check the functions you call inside the loops as "dd_bewerbung.f_trs_anrechnen" probably you can optimize them.

Comment: @Mihawk yes this was the first thing I did, the functions are executed fast. Here is explain plan for "dd_bewerbung.f_trs_anrechnen" function:    -----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation        | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|  1 |   FAST DUAL      |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please edit your question to include the cursors etc; IMO, pulling the data into arrays and then looping around the arrays is no faster (and may be slower!) than looping through the cursors. Far better would be to avoid looping over the cursors, if possible - or at least, stop looping within a loop. If you provide more details about your cursors, we may be able to help you improve your performance.

Comment: @Boneist I've edited my question, what do you mean by 'stop looping within a loop'? I think it's impossible, cause the elements of arrays used as function parameters, so anyway I have to loop over them

Comment: My gut feel is that you could combine all your logic into a single select statement, but without seeing the code behind the various functions that you have present, it's difficult to show you how.

Comment: I've been thinking of this too, but I guess it's not my case, cause for example the function "dd_side_arbeit.f()" has >400 lines of code and not just select statements, it does many calculations and checks and then returns some result set, another function is also quite long and I don't think I can rewite it.

Comment: @FPQ: How often do you run the report? Once a month? More often? I guess the report does most of the work in dd_side_arbeit.f function. 400 lines of code times 12000 times and then you extract piece of the result. Can't you precalculate the results of the function dd_side_arbeit.f and store them in a table, so that you can reuse the calculated results?